# Node express 404 error status code in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am getting an error status code 404 while calling a function locally in nodejs server through firebase serve command.

My schedule.js file

```
const scheduleOfScheduledQuiz = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getScheduledData();

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Scheduled for today:- ",
            data: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("erro", error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Something went wrong....!!!"
        })
    }
}

module.exports = {
    scheduleOfScheduledQuiz
}
```

getScheduledData() is a function which gets some data from the firebase realtime database

My index.js file

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const app = require("express")();

//path to scheduleOfScheduledQuiz() function file
const scheduleOfScheduledQuiz = require("./handlers/Quiz/Scheduled_Quiz/scheduler");

app.get("*/scheduled-quiz/schedule/", scheduleOfScheduledQuiz.scheduleOfScheduledQuiz);

exports.api = functions.runWith({
  memory: '2GB',
  timeoutSeconds: '60'
}).https.onRequest(app);
```

So the error what i am getting :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /predicta-6e51d/us-central1/api/scheduled-quiz/schedule/%0A</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

**with status code 404**

My package.json file

```
Global node js version - 12
firebase node js version - 10
"express": "^4.17.1",
"firebase": "^7.15.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.7.0",
```

I am running this function locally on my nodejs server through **firebase serve** command.

NOTE:- when i am trying to run the same function on some other file it is perfectly running but not in this file.

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Hi @AmanSingh the error 404 indicates that page is not being found, so, it seems that your `scheduled-quiz/schedule` is not in the path that you are directing it. Could you please try to change it to the same folder of the `index.js` file and call it again? It seems to be the most probable issue, based in the error and message.

Comment: @gso_gabriel Actually i have checked my path 10 times, its correct. One more issue i found today is that today i deployed my functions and when i try to call those functions api through postman i am getting the same error what i have mentioned above and one of my team mate calling the same api through postman in his system he is getting the response. I dont know why yhis issue is coming

Comment: Thanks for confirming @AmanSingh another reason for this to be occurring and considering that your colleague doesn't face it, might be related to permissions. In case you don't have permissions to run the functions/access the content, an error like this might be thrown. Could you please check if you have the same access/permissions as your colleague that doesn't face this issue?

Comment: @gso_gabriel yes i have the full access to my project.

Comment: If you have full access to the project and it's working for another user, I would recommend you to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support), so they can check further what is happening.